# Is high label cardinality but low metric/label count and infrequent sampling an acceptable use-case for Prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have a use-case of monitoring that I'm not entirely sure if it's a good
match for Prometheus or not, and I wanted to ask for opinions before I delve
deeper.

The numbers of what I'm going to store:

Only 1 metric.
That metric has 1 label with 1,000,000 to 2,000,000 distinct values.
The values are gauges (but does it make a difference if they are counters?)
Sample rate is once every 5 minutes. Retaining data for 180 days.

Estimated storage size if I have 1 million distinct label values:

(According to formula in Prometheus' documentation: retention_time_seconds *
ingested_samples_per_second * bytes_per_sample)

```
(24*60)/5=288 5-minute intervals in a day.

(180*288)           * (1,000,000)       * 2 = 103,680,000,000 ~= 100GB
samples/label-value   label-value-count   bytes/sample
```

So I assume 100-200GB will be required.

1. Is this estimation correct?
2. I read in multiple places about avoiding high-cardinality labels, and I would
   like to ask about this.  **Considering I will be looking at one time-series at a time** Is the problem with high-cardinality labels? Or
   having a high number of time-series?  As each label value produces another
   time-series?  I also read in multiple places that Prometheus can handle
   millions of time-series at once, so even if I have 1 label with one million
   distinct values, I should be fine in terms of time-series count, do I have to
   worry about the labels having high cardinality in this case?  I'm aware that
   it depends on the strength of the server, but assuming average capacity, I
   would like to know if Prometheus' implementation has a problem handling this
   case efficiently.
3. And also, if it's a matter of time-series count, am I correct in assuming
   that it will not make a significant difference between the following
   options?

   1. 1  metric      with 1 label of 1,000,000 distinct label values.
   2. 10 metrics each with 1 label of   100,000 distinct label values.
   3. X metrics each with 1 label of         Y distinct label values.
      where X * Y = 1,000,000

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

That might work, but it's not what Prometheus is designed for and you'll likely run into issues. You probably want a database rather than a monitoring system, maybe Cassandra here.

How the cardinality is split out across metrics won't affect ingestion performance, however it'll be relatively slow to have to read 1M series in a query.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! There will be no need to read 1M series in a query, only a single query at a time. Knowing that, does that change your answer? I will edit my question to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

Note that Victoria Metrics is an easy to configure backend for Prometheus which will reduce storage requirements significantly.